# Boto script to fetch out ec2 instances that doesn't have a specific tag (Name) with it

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

Can someone help me with a boto script that lists out ec2 instances which doesn't have a specific tag Name associated with it.

Value of Name can be anything. We just need instances for which Name has not been set.

I have tried this: is this correct? it is returning some instances but also getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try6.py", line 7, in <module>
    if 'Foo' not in [t['Key'] for t in i.tags]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable




import boto3

instances = [i for i in boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-1').instances.all()]

# Print instance_id of instances that do not have a Tag of Key='Foo'
for i in instances:
    if 'Foo' not in [t['Key'] for t in i.tags]:
        print i.instance_id
```

what will go in place of Foo
cos i have to list out instances which don't have a Name tag associated with them.
~

Comment: You are tagging with boto, boto3 as well as aws-cli. Choose which you are using, how much have you read about it, what you have tried; and then ask a well-formed question

Comment: It might be a better fit to use AWS Config to do this

Answer (score 1):

```
instances=boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='eu-west-1').instances.all()

for i in instances:
    if 'Foo' not in [t['Key'] for t in i.tags]:
        print i.instance_id
```

I think this works where your example did not as .instances.all() returns a boto3.resources.collection.ec2.instancesCollection

So the [] construct makes a list of a single boto3.resources.collection.ec2.instancesCollection object!  Whereas just using the object in a loop works as the object has an iterator defined